# Как подключить пространство имен filesystem к VisualStudio 19

Tags: c++

Подключил  к проекту `#include <filesystem>`, но для использования функций ни как не удается подключить пространство имен `filesystem`, может есть с этим какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел сам тупил

Answer (score 1):

В настройках проекта не указал применение стиля C++17()
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]